# XML Editing POWER SHELL 2.0 - parsing : Pipeline Expression error

Tags: xml, powershell, expression

With the help of a few folks here, I was able to put together the following script.  I am trying to parse XML data into the event viewer from the *.xml files I have sitting in a directory. for security reasons, I need to pull some info out before creating the Event Log.   Originally I was replacing a key word in the file, but the software I am using has a problem with that, so I had to create a LastRun.txt file for checking the file every so often.  I don't want to keep alarming on the XML file if it still exists in the folder.

**I am getting the following error when I try to run it:**
It reports: *Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline. At line:20 char:132*

Which starts with the " **'** "  here:  '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b', '$3-$2-$1'})

```powershell
#get last time the powershell script was run
$LastRunStamp = Get-Content c:\test\lastRunStamp.txt

#write current timestamp to file
Get-Date > c:\test\lastRunStamp.txt

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem c:\test\*.xml)) 
{
    #if the file was modified since the last script run
    if($file.LastWriteTime -ge $LastRunStamp)
    {
        #instatiate XML document object
        $xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument

        #load up the XML contents into the object
        $xdoc.load($file)

        #check the value of the priority XML tag if  it contains Major then write to event log
        if ($xdoc.SelectNode("//priorityname") -eq 'Major') {
                        $content = ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName) | {$_ -replace '.abc.com', ' '} | {$_ -replace '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b', '$3-$2-$1'})

            Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'Verint Alert' `
                                                            -EntryType Warning -EventId 1 `
                                                            -Message "Triggered Alarm $content";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing `ForEach-Object` with your current code but you dont really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no other issues in the code your problem is, of course, this line

```
 $content = ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName) | {$_ -replace '.abc.com', ' '} | {$_ -replace '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b', '$3-$2-$1'})
```

You have a pipe but no cmdlet to feed the information into, hence the error. So with your current code you can do this.

```
$content = ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName) | 
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '.abc.com', ' '} |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b', '$3-$2-$1'})
```

I only put in the newlines to make it easier to read here.

**Alternate**

`-replace` functions as an array operator and you can chain them. So this is also an option.

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName) -replace '.abc.com', ' ' -replace '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b', '$3-$2-$1'
```

Comment: thank you so much!!    The last issue I have with it is getting:

Bad argument to operator '-ge': Could not compare "4/20/2015 2:30:24 PM" to "System.Object[]". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime".".
At line:10 char:31
+     if($file.LastWriteTime -ge <<<<  $LastRunStamp)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument

Comment: I assume I need a function for the time stamp comparison

Comment: @Delaney does that file only contain the one line?

Comment: I feel that it has multiple lines in which case I'm not sure what your logic would be.

Comment: Don't. Code in comments can be hard to read you can use back ticks like this: ` code and stuff ` without the spaces... cant do it right in comments. @Delaney this might server better as its own question since it is a different issue.

Comment: I finally solved this problem.  I would LOVE to post the solution to all those that may stumble upon this..   I dont know how to insert the code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the resolution for those that may stumble upon this:

## get last time the powershell script was run

$LastRunStamp = (Get-Item c:\test\lastRunStamp.txt).LastWriteTime.DateTime

## write current timestamp to file

Get-Date > c:\test\lastRunStamp.txt

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem c:\test*.xml)) 
{
    #calculate the time difference between file modified time and last time script was run
    $span = new-timespan -start $file.LastWriteTime.DateTime  -end $LastRunStamp

```
 #if the file was modified since the last time the  script run value will be less than 0    
if($span.TotalSeconds -le 0)
{

            #instantiate XML document object
            $xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument

            #load up the XML contents into the object
            $xdoc.load($file)

            #check the value of the priority XML tag if  it contains Major then write to event log
            if ($xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//priorityname").innertext -eq 'Major') 
            {

                #get the content of XML
                $content = [string]([IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)) 

                #mask the FQDN's
                $content = $content.replace(".ngd.com",".sensored").replace(".ad.local",".sensored FQDN")

                #regex pattern to detect IP Addresses
                $pattern = "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b"

                #use regex to mask IP addresses
                $contentScrubbed = [regex]::replace($content, $pattern, "sensored IP Address")   

                Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Application” `
                –EntryType Information –EventID 1 `
                -Message ("Triggered Alarm" + $contentScrubbed)
            }                                   
}
```

}